# error : 'Processus' object has no attribute 'outil_set' - django

Tags: django, django-queryset

hello I want to show the 'outils' in my 'Processus'
so in my views I did something like that :

```
def processus(request, pk_test):

   processus = Processus.objects.get(id=pk_test)

   outils = processus.outil_set.all()

   total_outils = outils.count()

   context={
       'processus':processus,
       'outils':outils,

       'total_outils':total_outils,
 }
```

but it doesn't work it show an error 'Processus' object has no attribute 'outil_set'

this is my models.py

```
    class outil(ressource):
        nom_outil = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        proprieté = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        technique_id = models.ForeignKey(technique, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nom_outil

    class Processus(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        proprieté = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        outils = models.ManyToManyField(outil)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the relation is `outils`, so you access this with `processus.outils.all()`:

```
def processus(request, pk_test):
    processus = Processus.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    outils = processus.outils.all()
    total_outils = outils.count()
    context={
        'processus':processus,
        'outils': outils,
        'total_outils':total_outils,
    }
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`outil`</s> to `Outil`.